# php - create x number of copies of array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, clone

I'm looking more for guidance here than actual code. I already know how I can do this; just wondering if there's a better way.

I have a variable `$x`, which is an integer. Can be any number. I have an array, `$items`.

```
$items = Array('qty'=>3, 'name'=>'pizza');
```

I want to create `$x` copies of `$items`, each of which will become a 'subarray' of a new array called `$newItems`.

I know I can do a for loop sort of like this:

```
for($i=1;$1<=$x,$i++) {
   $newItems[$x] = $items;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? (The example is simplified so if it were just like this, it wouldn't be a problem to do the loop. But in reality, I have a parent array called `$menu` that has multiple `$menu_items` nodes, so I'm already doing a `foreach($menu_items as $id->$items)`, which the above loop would then need to be nested in. It would be nice if there was some function I don't know about where I could just say "make `$x` copies of this array`.

Comment: [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill) (or [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys)) might help here.

Comment: $newItems = array_fill(0, $x, $items);`

Comment: why do you need copies of this array?

Comment: RocketHazmat, @MarkBaker - I'm not familiar with that one. Just looked at php.net; am I correct in assuming that "mixed value" in the second param can be anything, even another array? If so, I think this would work. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The second param can be anything (except perhaps a resource, I've never tried with a resource) -  scalar, array, object, even nested arrays of objects or functions

Comment: @MarkBaker - thanks. In your example, what is the zero? The documentation shows that it only takes two params, not three.

Comment: The first argument is the start value for the array index: starting at key 0, create an array with 6 entries (indexed 0-5) each one containing $items

Comment: Whoops, never mind. I was looking at the doc for array_fill_keys, which @RocketHazmat initially mentioned. I see that array_fill does take three params.

Comment: @EmmyS, in fact `array_fill` takes three parameters.

Comment: @MarkBaker - that's what I needed, thanks. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [array_fill()](http://www.php.net/function.array-fill)

```
$newItems = array_fill(0, $x, $items);
```